# Guava: Copy-Constructor for graphs

Tags: java, constructor, guava, graph-theory, factory

I'm searching for a copy-constructor for graphs in guava. So far I've tried this:

```
copy = GraphBuilder.from(g).build();
```

"from(..)" only copies the properties (directed/undirected) of the graph, not the edges/vertices.

I'm searching for an actual copy with vertices/edges. Does guava support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [Graphs.copyOf](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/Graphs.html#copyOf-com.google.common.graph.Graph-).